# django production server: root path

Tags: django, path, root, production

I am developing a django application. On the development server, everything works just fine.
On the production server (using apache), nothing is working.

1/ I have the error *TemplateDoesNotExist at /*.

In my settings.py file:

`SITE_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))`. This is the project root path.

```
templateDir = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates/')
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    templateDir
)
```

This is the templates path.

2/ If I change SITE_ROOT with the absolute path of the project:

```
SITE_ROOT="/var/www/europolix"
```

Templates seem to be recognize but I have another mistake:
*No module named getEurlexIdsFunctions*
Here is the code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('import')
import getEurlexIdsFunctions as eurlexIds
```

I think that once again the problem comes from a relative path. Apache seems to search 'import' in "var/www/" and not in "var/www/europolix/". Am I right?

Here is my apache configuration:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /europolix /var/www/europolix/europolix/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/europolix/
<Directory /var/www/europolix/>
   <Files wsgi.py>
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
   </Files>
</Directory>
```

Is it a problem of root path not recognized, or is there another problem?

Many thanks.

Comment: Just a tip for a good module is UniPath. It helps with paths in a more  normal person language way.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more or give an example? Is it a better / cleaner solution than what I used?

Comment: here's the documentation: https://github.com/mikeorr/Unipath

Answer (score 1):

Well, a couple of things. When working with `settings.py` is better to declare all the paths as absolute paths. I see in your code that you have this line

```
SITE_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))
```

for site's root but I think is better if you use `__file__` global variable instead of `__name__`. Like this:

```
SITE_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

I have a django app in production server and all I had to add to my `httpd.conf` about `wsgi` was the `load_module` directive and this line inside the virtual host

```
WSGIScriptAlias / C:/Users/ike/Documents/Work/Sincronoz/code/apache/django.wsgi
```

specifying the alias to the `django.wsgi` script as the root.

Then in `django.wsgi` script I have this code:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(r'<full site root to where is settings.py>')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'my_project_module.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I think you're better off working with absolute paths and when you got it all working then try to accommodate it for your needs with maybe relative path if you have to.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

in django project in file wsgi.py i add this 3 lines

```
import sys
DJANGO_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)),'..')
sys.path.append(DJANGO_PATH)
```